# How to divide a column to a number in bash shell if the other column had a condition true?

Tags: bash

I have a data frame like this:

```
G   0   0   255 0   255 0  
T   1   0   255 0   253 2  
T   2   0   255 0   252 3  
A   3   0   255 0   254 1  
T   4   0   255 0   253 2  
T   5   0   255 0   253 2  
A   6   0   255 0   254 1  
T   7   0   255 0   252 3  
G   8   0   255 0   254 1  
T   9   0   255 0   254 1  
A   10  0   255 0   253 2  
T   11  0   255 0   253 2  
G   12  0   255 0   254 1
```

I want to divide column **7** by **255** `($7/255)` and make a new column for that if the value in column **1** was equal to **G**.

I want an output like this:

```
G   0   0   255 0   255 0   0  
T   1   0   255 0   253 2  
T   2   0   255 0   252 3  
A   3   0   255 0   254 1  
T   4   0   255 0   253 2  
T   5   0   255 0   253 2  
A   6   0   255 0   254 1  
T   7   0   255 0   252 3  
G   8   0   255 0   254 1   0.00392157  
T   9   0   255 0   254 1  
A   10  0   255 0   253 2  
T   11  0   255 0   253 2  
G   12  0   255 0   254 1   0.00392157
```

The following code does the division for all rows in column **7**. I think I should define a loop and if statement somewhere but I do not know how? any help would be really appreciated.

```
awk '{$8 = $7 / 255}1' file | column -t > new_file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '$1 =="G" {$8 = $7 / 255} 1' file > new_file
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works, but in those rows equal to "G" the delimitator is space while my file is tab-delimited.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it: awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 =="G" {$8 = $7 / 255} 1' file > new_file

Comment: @Vahid, for completeness, specify the *input* field separator as well: `-F '\t'`